# React PrivateRoute not spreading rest/props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to create my own PrivateRoute Route Wrapper similar to [this demonstration](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Of course it isn't working.

Here is how I call the route:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route... <Other basic Routes>
    <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.authed} path="/account" user={currentUser} handler={this.handler} component={Account} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Here is the PrivateRoute function:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location }}
      } />}
    />
  )
}
```

If I console.log component, authed, or rest from the PrivateRoute function they look fine. It's just that props is always null and doesn't pass down into my component. I'm at a loss.

I'm importing from react and react-router-dom:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

I'm using these versions of dependencies for react.

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "4.2.2"
```

Also, if I just move the code out of the PrivateRoute function and put it inline on the route it works fine. It's only when I make a generic Route wrapper that I start having the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me know if the duplicate doesn't answer your question

Comment: That makes sense, but wouldn't that keep me from being dynamic? What if I don't want to pass 'exact' or 'strict'? Am I correct in thinking that they would just be null and that's ok?

Comment: Well, I just tried it an it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, if you don't pass exact or strict, they would be undefined, which is alright